# SQL Server 2012 SP2 hotfix error message

Tags: sql-server-2012, hotfix, service-pack

At the end of applying the `Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5343` hotfix, I got the error below (the hotfix apply went successfully).

> SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:
>
> The NT service 'MSSQLSERVER' could not be started.
>
> Error code 0x84B20001.
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&EvtType=0xAE7B8BF3%25400xF762992B%25401202%25401

Has anyone else encountered the same issue, or this is a known issue?

Comment: I did check the bootstrap logs but not much info to proceed.

Comment: Did you reboot the server after applying the hotfix?  What happens when you remove the hotfix?  What KB article is the hotfix associated with?